# Can I send a sysex message using csound's midiout opcode? And how?

Tags: midi, csound, sysex

System Exclusive MIDI messages can be of an arbitrary length. Can csound's midiout opcode accommodate for that? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Csound's `midiout` supports only channel messages.

To get SysEx messages, you would have to use some external tool to convert some custom controller messages into SysEx messages. (See [Send MIDI SysEx message based on CC or PC message](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/75106/8776), which has no answer; I don't know if `midish` would help, or if you'd have to write your own software.)